# Reset local Git branch to remote

Tags: git

Is there a single command that (after `git fetch`) resets the working copy to the state the remote branch is in?

For example, I have branch `foo` checked out and it is tracking `origin/foo`. I make some commits and local changes. Now I want to discard all those commits and changes and reset the local file set to `origin/foo`. So I run `git fetch` and then?

The closest I got is

```
git reset --hard origin/`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
```

but that is almost impossible to remember and only works in shells that support backticks.

Comment: That question is about a completely different problem, pretty much the only common aspect is the title of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`git reset --hard @{u}`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches) will do what you want:

> When you have a tracking branch set up, you can reference its upstream branch with the `@{upstream}` or `@{u}` shorthand. So if you’re on the `master` branch and it’s tracking `origin/master`, you can say something like `git merge @{u}` instead of `git merge origin/master` if you wish.